# MySQL ORDER BY using filesort (2 joined tables)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

I have strange problem on query optimization. SQL is generated by ORM-like library and something bad has been detected only after reading megabytes of SQL logs.

```
SELECT  
  `ct_pricelistentry`.`uid` as `uid`, `ct_pricelistentry`.`skuGroup` as `skuGroup`
FROM 
  `ct_pricelistentry` INNER JOIN `lct_set` 
ON `lct_set`.`parent_uid`='SET:ALLPRICELISTENTRIES' AND 
   `lct_set`.`ref_uid`=`ct_pricelistentry`.`uid` 
WHERE 
  (`isGroup` IS FALSE) AND 
  (`isService` IS FALSE) AND 
  (`brand` = 'BRAND:5513f43697d637.00632331' OR `brand` IS NULL) 
ORDER BY `skuGroup` ASC
```

EXPLAIN says:

> '1', 'SIMPLE', 'ct_pricelistentry', 'ALL', 'PRIMARY', NULL, NULL, NULL, '34591', '**Using where; Using filesort**'
>
> '1', 'SIMPLE', 'lct_set', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '292', 'const,dealers_v2.ct_pricelistentry.uid', '1', 'Using where; Using index'

Note: all needed indexes are presented including `skuGroup`. But the index `skuGroup`still is not listed in EXPLAIN `possible_keys`. It also cannot be forced by `FORCE INDEX` (it just disables all indexes).

After some research I found hacky solution but not sure it works as indended:

1. Add `FORCE INDEX (skuGroup)`,
2. Add to the `WHERE` clause dummy `AND (skuGroup IS NULL OR skuGroup IS NOT NULL)` part.

Following query

```
SELECT  
  `ct_pricelistentry`.`uid` as `uid`, `ct_pricelistentry`.`skuGroup` as `skuGroup`
FROM 
  `ct_pricelistentry` FORCE INDEX (`skuGroup`) INNER JOIN `lct_set` 
ON `lct_set`.`parent_uid`='SET:ALLPRICELISTENTRIES' AND
   `lct_set`.`ref_uid`=`ct_pricelistentry`.`uid` 
WHERE 
  (`isGroup` IS FALSE) AND 
  (`isService` IS FALSE) AND 
  (`brand` = 'BRAND:5513f43697d637.00632331' OR `brand` IS NULL) AND
  (`skuGroup` IS NULL OR `skuGroup` IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY `skuGroup` ASC
```

gives EXPLAIN without filesort so it seems to use the index to fetch ordered rows:

> '1', 'SIMPLE', 'ct_pricelistentry', 'range', 'skuGroup', 'skuGroup', '768', NULL, '16911', '**Using where**'
>
> '1', 'SIMPLE', 'lct_set', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '292', 'const,dealers_v2.ct_pricelistentry.uid', '1', 'Using where; Using
>    index'

Whats happening at all?
Is it a MySQL bug? I've tested on MySQL 5.1 - 5.5 - the same results. Do you have more predictable/stable solutions?

```
---- CREATE TABLE ----
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lct_set` (
  `parent_uid` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `ref_uid` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`parent_uid`,`ref_uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `BACK_PRIMARY` (`ref_uid`,`parent_uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ct_pricelistentry` (
  `uid` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `refcount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isDisposed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` text,
  `isGroup` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentEntry` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `externalUID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productCode` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `skuGroup` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `measureUnit` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemClassExternalUID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemClassName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemClassDescription` text,
  `itemClassComments` text,
  `itemClassAttachments` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(48) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `priceGroups` text,
  `productAttributes` text,
  `constituents` text,
  `position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isService` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stackability` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `test1` (`uid`,`skuGroup`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `sku` (`sku`),
  KEY `itemClassExternalUID` (`itemClassExternalUID`),
  KEY `parentEntry` (`parentEntry`),
  KEY `position` (`position`),
  KEY `externalUID` (`externalUID`),
  KEY `productCode` (`productCode`),
  KEY `skuGroup` (`skuGroup`),
  KEY `brand` (`brand`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked the two queries to see which is faster? Filesort is not always the worst option.

Comment: Yes, using filesort 0.0790 s. vs index fetch 0.0041 s.

Comment: volume - 20220 rows in result set

Comment: Using `skuGroup` as an index should actually not help - it will still have to fetch all rows from the table to check the conditions, but now in  random access order, so it should actually be slower. Can you test your two queries again, but in a different order (the second one first), so your speedbump doesn't result from buffering? Assuming `brand` is part of `ct_pricelistentry` and `uuid` is the primary key (and guessing your booleans are not very distinctive), I would recommend an index on `brand`, and to prevent filesort, use a composite index `(brand, skuGroup)`.

Comment: I used SQL_NO_CACHE and tried them in different order - using filesort is always slower. Index on `brand` works but actually there are 3 brands only and it is not distinctive just as booleans.. Yes, when using skuGroup it must fetch all rows but at least they are in needed order already (I don't understand how random access read may occur? beside low-level details )

Comment: The main question for me is why do i need to use skuGroup field in where clause just to have ability to force using that index. maybe it will stop working in other cases... and the other question is how to avoid using FORCE INDEX having same execution plan.

Comment: Can you post the "Create Table" info?

Comment: Create Table info posted

Comment: ON `lct_set`.`parent_uid`='SET:ALLPRICELISTENTRIES' AND                       

Why is this in the "ON" clause and not in the "WHERE" clause?

Comment: Have you tried running ANALYSE TABLE which will update the cardinality of the index http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-index.html "An estimate of the number of unique values in the index. This is updated by running ANALYZE TABLE or myisamchk -a. Cardinality is counted based on statistics stored as integers, so the value is not necessarily exact even for small tables. The higher the cardinality, the greater the chance that MySQL uses the index when doing joins."

Comment: Because it is part of PRIMARY compound key. Explain says in ref column about it: const,dealers_v2.result_table.uid, therefore it is recognized as const successfully. Anyway I've tried to move it to WHERE, explain shows completely the same plan, looks like there is no difference for planner where to place this equation..

Comment: ANALYZE made no valuable effect. i tried it too.

Comment: Why `JOIN` to `lct_set` at all?  You get nothing from it other than to see if such a row exists.

Comment: @Jaydee - for a non-LEFT join, `ON` and `WHERE` are entirely(?) interchangeable.  It is 'proper' to use `ON` for tying the tables together and `WHERE` for filtering.  It is (so far), unclear which purpose `parent_uid` serves.  Mikhail, can you answer that?

Comment: `lct_set` contains association between set object (its uid stored in parent_uid) and value object (ref_uid), it is ORM engine basic impementation of set over relational database. In other words we can have multiple virtual tables having same structure ('repositories' in terms of engine). Here (in the example query) we want only those belonging given parent_uid ('SET:ALLPRICELISTENTRIES')

Comment: i used EXPLAIN EXTENDED and SHOW WARNINGS, mysql rewrites ON to WHERE (so no ON clauses at all), doesnt matter where to insert conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The fix** Using the `INDEX(skuGroup)` avoids the filesort, but prevents any useful filtering.  Optimizing the filtering is more important than avoiding the filesort.

Remove the `FORCE` and add this 'composite' index

```
INDEX(isGroup, isService, brand) -- (in any order)
```

It should help, but probably won't prevent "using filesort".  The `OR` is the killer.

To prevent the use of filesort for `ORDER BY`, you need a single (usually composite) index that includes *all* of the `WHERE` clause, *plus* the `ORDER BY` column(s).  In constructing such an index, the *only* things that can be handled in the `WHERE` are and'd together '=' clauses.  Anything else (such as your `OR`) prevents the optimization.

**Why OR hurts** Think of it this way...  Suppose there were a long printed list of names sorted by last name + first name.  And the query asked for `WHERE last = 'Karakulov' ORDER BY first`.  You would jump to the first Karakulov, and there would be all the first names in order.  Now suppose you wanted `WHERE (last = 'Karakulov' OR last = 'James') ORDER BY first`.  You could get all your relatives and all my relatives, but you still need to shuffle them together to do the `ORDER BY first`.  MySQL has one technique for that: filesort (and a tmp table leading up to it.)

As a consolation, filesort's temp table is usually an in-memory MEMORY table, so it is reasonably fast.

A workaround is *sometimes* to turn `OR` into `UNION`.  (It probably would not help for your query.)

**Some schema critique, and other notes...**

The `UNIQUE` key is useless because the `PRIMARY KEY` already declares `uid` to be "unique".

`VARCHAR(48) utf8` is a rather clumsily big key.  Is it some form of UUID?  If so, I have nasty things to say about randomness and charset and size.

Some uids are (48), some are (255); was this deliberate?

Get rid of `(`skuGroup`IS NULL OR`skuGroup`IS NOT NULL)` -- The Optimizer is probably not smart enough to realize that this is always "TRUE" !

`FORCE INDEX` may work today, but could backfire tomorrow.  Get rid of it.

What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  It should be about 70% of *available* RAM if you have at least 4GB of ram.  If you left it at some low default, then you are probably I/O-bound, hence slow.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE lct_set` -- something strange is going on in the `JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Filter conditions are formed dynamically and It is not pragmatic to create all possible combinations... anyway use of skuGroup index alone for ORDER BY is 1) possible 2) accelerating query  about  5x times.. there is no reason to restrict this. Of course in other cases it maybe slower, then I choose other strategies.

Comment: Because of caching, I don't trust that that index is really any faster.  It could be that when you ran it, everything was cached, so _that time_ it ran fast.

Comment: That ORM should be shot for generating `(skuGroupIS NULL ORskuGroupIS NOT NULL)`.  (I spend too much of my time helping people get around the messes that 3rd party software packages generate.)  I hope that the ORM gives you enough control to fix some of my other suggestions.